# Return everything starting from last occurrence of pattern

Tags: regex, autohotkey

Consider this string:

```
apple banana carrot dessert carrot carrot apple banana banana carrot dessert dessert
```

I want to **match and return everything starting from the last occurrence of "carrot"** (whether it's itself included or not — let's say it should be), which would give:

```
carrot dessert dessert
```

This is the farthest I've gotten:

```
.+(carrot.+)$
```

[Demo regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9nBc5R/1)

I'm not sure how to return *only* Group 1 and not the entire Group 0 (which Group 1 is a part of). Clearly I'm misunderstanding some basic mechanics of regex. Thank you for reading.

I'm coding an AutoHotKey script.

Comment: What is your regex tool/language? e.g. in PCRE one can do: `.+\K\bcarrot.+$`

Comment: looks like pcre here. If so, i suggest using something like this: `carrot(.+?)$`

Comment: It's for an AutoHotKey script

Comment: @anubhava op wants to capture the trailing part

Comment: Looks like `\K` is supported in AutoHotKey so use my first suggestion

Comment: @anubhava Your solution worked perfectly! I ended up using something like `.+\K[0-9].+$` for a similar purpose. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoHotKey [supports PCRE](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm) so you can indeed make use of `\K` as pointed out by anubhava in the comments.

If you also want to match `carrot` if it is the only thing in the line, you can write the pattern using `.*` which means 0 or more, instead of `.+` which means 1 or more.

```
.*\K\bcarrot\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BmlCHx/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
str := "apple banana carrot dessert carrot carrot apple banana banana carrot dessert dessert"
RegExMatch(str, "O).*(carrot.*)", o)
MsgBox % o[1]
```